# error getting first child element of node with tinyxml2

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

I have this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scene>
  <file>sphere.d3</file>
</scene>
```

And this function that should put all the "file" elements into a vector

```
vector<string> loadXML(string file){

    vector<string> files;

    XMLDocument xml_doc;
    xml_doc.LoadFile(file);

    if(xml_doc.ErrorID() != 0) {
        cout << xml_doc.ErrorName() << endl;
        return files;
    }

    XMLNode* scene = xml_doc.FirstChild();
    if(scene == nullptr){
        cout << "No Root Found\n" << endl;
        return files;
    }

    string temp;

    XMLElement* shape = scene -> FirstChildElement("file"); //error getting this element
    if(shape == nullptr){
        cout << "Error Reading XML file\n";
        return files;
    }

    temp = shape -> GetText();
    files.push_back(temp);

    while(shape != nullptr){
        shape = shape -> NextSiblingElement("file");
        if(shape == nullptr){
            cout << "Error Reading XML file";
            return files;
        }
        temp = shape -> GetText();
        files.push_back(temp);
    }

    return files;

}
```

however, when trying to get the first "file" element from the root it gives me a null ptr.
any help would be very appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please consider doing it this way instead:

```
tinyxml2::XMLElement* pScene = xml_doc.FirstChildElement("Scene");
if (pScene != nullptr)
{
    //...
}
```

That is how I read the first element from a XML data file and do not encounter issues.